# Hats can overflow, covering links in review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, winter-bash

[This user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)'s hat covers text in the review queue, making the links harder to click.

[image]

It also covers some of their information on their profile, making it hard to see their reputation and badges.

[image]

Comment: If this really bothers you that much, you can write a userscript that will hide hats in certain pages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they can overflow, but the behavior is by design. Unless there's a specific strong reason to disallow that, we are not going to change this right now. Also, it plays well with our site's name...

Comment: If the first two or three users shown in the review queue all had their hats like that, the links we be nearly unclickable. Admittedly, the links aren't something I'd often use, but still.

Comment: You could set `pointer-events: none;` on the hats which should allow you to click through in most browsers (except IE iirc), can't see any drawback to that.

Comment: TIL: this website is called "HatOverflow"