# Make hat disappear on hover

Tags: feature-request, design, winter-bash-2016

No this is not a question for hat-haters. The problem here is that any user with the right hat in the right place with the right size can cover their reputation and even some badge counts:

[image]

I actually have at least 10k rep here and not 0.8k rep which makes no sense at all:

[image]

I mean you could go to the user's Activity page to find out but the hat seems a little weird covering the reputation count. This hat placement is also visible in the topbar where it magically floats in the whitespace below it or in chat where half of it disappears.

So I suggest that if someone hovers over the hat directly, it "disappears" or at least becomes translucent so anything below it becomes readable at least. When you are no longer hovering over the hat, it reappears back to its magical state.

Comment: How did you manage 2 golds with 0.8k reputation ;-)?

Comment: @Bathsheba 100 questions with a score of 1, no downvotes or close votes, all on separate days to receive Socratic. Then visited the site for 100 days for Fanatic. The other badges are just question badges related to views and Enthusiast.

Comment: No, it's fun how it is

Comment: @Bathsheba Ask great questions and then delete them after they get enough upvotes for a gold badge.

Comment: Related: [Hats can overflow, covering links in review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288355/307988)

Comment: you have a point here. Especially on the "cover username" part

Comment: @Bathsheba Couple of famous questions. I've seen more gold with less rep.