# Hats can push time stamp to the right in question list

Tags: bug, timestamps, winter-bash

Hats can be positioned in a way that leaves the bounds of a user's image, but apparently this can also affect time stamp positioning when browsing questions.

In this image, a hat is pushing the time stamp to the right, and the right part of the stamp is cut off due to overflow. The question above it shows what a normal time stamp looks like.

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288355/hats-can-overflow-covering-links-in-review-queue)

Answer (score 2):

Well that's by design because hats can do that!

Like in my [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288613/make-hat-disappear-on-hover), the hat can cover parts of the user's reputation and badge counts. Probably in order that the "{action}" in:

> {action} {date} at {time}

isn't covered, the CSS for that text moves it away from the hat so it is clearly seen for other purposes. It would look really weird if this is all you saw:

> mins ago

on your question right? Your hat becomes troublesome because users can't immediately see how many minutes ago and what happened (modified, answered, or asked). Thus this "self-defense" mechanism is perfectly fine. Otherwise, hats won't be able to exit the top of the avatar which would make lots of hat-wearing avatars look really weird...

In terms of the cut-off end, the CSS could be modified so the font is slightly smaller is it can wrap or modified so that the border is expanded so that one digit is not cut off.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't need to chop off the overflow, though? There was white space to the right.

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: Look at the image where the time is cut off *on the right*

Comment: Check my edit please

Comment: I understand that. That is my solution to SE so they can apply it