# Hats break formatting for the revision

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, winter-bash

Hats break formatting for [the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607018/201):

> [image: out of space]

Also applicable for localized sites, [like ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4354/176217).

I think my post is not a dup of [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288706) because in current case timestamp is not cutted off, but overhangs.

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug!

Comment: @Cai in current case timestamp is not cutted off, like in suggested dup, but overhangs.

Comment: It's the same issue though. I agree that the hidden overflow in the dupe is a problem but overhanging is better than being covered by hats.