# Alignment for upvote triangles

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

In the mobile web for [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289084/339911) triangle links for upvoting comments are not aligned vertically:

> [image: triangles]

Occurs for any pair of comments where one of them has upvotes and another hasn't.

If comment has been upvoted and then reverted triangle shifts to the left:

> [image: upvote and revert]

Comment: At least I'm good for something :)

Comment: @Cai I can find bugs even for messages describing a feature!